Expanding an Existing Oracle Linux Cluster
I'm seeking assistance with a situation involving an Oracle Linux 7.9 cluster that's currently running on a VMware virtual machine environment. We have two nodes in this cluster, labeled A and B.
Our technical management team has decided to upgrade these servers, and they've expressed a desire to move away from the current setup in favor of establishing a new environment.
The current cluster setup includes corosync and pacemaker for clustering, as well as opendkim and sendmail, which we utilize for SMTP services.
Here's my question:
Is it possible to add two additional servers to our existing cluster? If so, do these new servers need to be identical to the current ones in terms of operating system and application versions? Or can we integrate servers with a newer OS and updated versions of the applications (corosync, pacemaker, opendkim, and sendmail)?
Alternatively, would it be more advisable to start fresh and build a new cluster from the ground up?
I'm looking for your expert advice, help, suggestions, and answers on this matter.
Thank you very much in advance for your assistance.

New hardware is a logical upgrade moment for your software stack as well, especially since Oracle 7 will be reaching EOL pretty soon. In theory you can mix corosync and pacemaker versions to some degree I think , but in practice Oracle 7 and oracle 9 versions lie 8 years apart and that may require some tuning and hacks to get to work, if compatible at all. In addition  I always find HA / failover clusters quite frail and likely to suffer catastrophic failures due to the most unexpected  causes and effects. And I wouldn't chance it.

I'd rather create a new cluster, test extensively with new versions of all your software, update your manuals & procedures etc and then migrate "the old fashioned way" with downtime, rather than by adding cluster members, failing over services to both  new cluster members and to new software versions.
